# onConfigChange Android 2.3 with NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread

My Fragments are not creating whenever i clicked an item in my NavigationDrawer in 2.3(device with sliding keyboard) but when i tried opening it(keyboard) even for a little the fragment shows up.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

while my manifest has

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

basically we don't support landscape.
thanks

Comment: Do you call syncState() in onPostCreate() method? And remove super.onCC() call.:)

Comment: i have syncstate in onpostcreate and i did remove the onConfigChange fragments doesn't show up.

Comment: Don't remove entire onConfigChange just the super call.

Comment: still the same Nikola